# How should I solve combination addition like this?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> $${2\choose 2} {10\choose 3}+{3 \choose 2}{9 \choose 3}+{4 \choose 2}{8 \choose 3}+{5 \choose 2}{7 \choose 3}+{6 \choose 2}{6 \choose 3}+{7 \choose 2}{5 \choose 3}+{8 \choose 2}{4 \choose 3}+{9 \choose 2}{3 \choose 3}={13 \choose 6}$$

I am supposed to get the answer ${13\choose 6}$. I wonder if there is any formula for combination addition like this or are there some tricks to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use the identity ${a \choose b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$ to simplify the expression?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404581/proving-binomnm2-binomn-1m-n-m1-binommm-binomn2m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count 6-subsets of $\{1,\dots,13\}$ by conditioning on the third smallest element $k$, which must be at least 3 and at most 10.  For example, if $k=5$, then there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two smaller elements from $\{1,\dots,4\}$ and $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to choose three larger elements from $\{6,\dots,13\}$.  This combinatorial proof shows that $$\sum_{k=3}^{10} \binom{k-1}{2}\binom{13-k}{3}=\binom{13}{6}.$$

More generally, Identity 137 in *Proofs That Really Count* is:
$$\sum_{j=r}^{n+r-k} \binom{j-1}{r-1}\binom{n-j}{k-r}=\binom{n}{k},$$
and the same combinatorial proof is given.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last part. How to convert the combination with sigma notation to the final answer?

Comment: The proof of equality is combinatorial, showing that both sides count the same quantity in two different ways.