# Is my proof by double counting correct?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I need to prove the following equality:
$$\sum_{j=k}^{n-m}{j\choose k}{n-j \choose m} = {n+1 \choose k+m+1}$$
That is what I came up with:

Say we have a fence with $n$ sections and $n+1$ posts. We want to color $k+m$ of the sections.

On LHS We choose a fence post between the $k$th and the $(n-m)$th. On its left there are at least $k$ sections, we color $k$ of them. On its right there are at least $m$ sections, we color $m$ of them.

On RHS we choose $k+m+1$ fence posts. For the $k$ posts on the left, we color the the section adjacent to them on the right. The $(k+1)$th post divides the $k$ and the $m$ posts, as we did before. Then we remain with $m$ posts. We will color the sections adjacent to them on the left.

These are two different ways to count the same thing, thus equality. $\square$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I solve combination addition like this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506383/how-should-i-solve-combination-addition-like-this)

Comment: I'm not convinced.  On the LHS, suppose we have two adjacent posts between the $k$th and the $(n-m)$th and that the section between them isn't colored.  Can't we get the coloring by choosing either one of the posts?  It seems like you have double counting on the LHS to me.

Comment: @saulspatz suppose you color that section for one post. Then for the other, if you color that section it will not be a $k$ $m$ split. It will be $k \pm 1$ and $m \mp 1$

Comment: I'm saying that the same coloring can arise for two choices.  Other colorings are irrelevant.

Comment: I understad what you say now. What if the post that separates the two sides is included in the choice? So for every coloring there will also be the location of that post that separates $k$ and $m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. A slightly simpler way of expressing the same basic idea would be: The right-hand side counts the subsets of $[n+1]$ with $k+m+1$ elements. The left-hand side counts the same thing by enumerating the subsets according to their $(k+1)$-th smallest element $j+1$, which can be anything from $k+1$ to $n-m+1$, with $k$ elements chosen from the $j$ elements below it and $m$ elements chosen from the $n-j$ elements above it.